# JSON formatting using group by and table valued function

Tags: sql-server, query, json

I want this query to group based on `ClientContactGroupID`.

```
select cg.ClientContactGroupID,ClientID,ContactGroupName
     , gcon.ClientContactID,gcon.ClientContactGroupID
     , gcon.FirstName
     , gcon.LastName,gcon.Email
     , gcon.ProfileImage,gcon.MobilePhone 
from ClientContactGroup cg 
cross apply dbo.Func_GroupContacts(cg.ClientContactGroupID) gcon 
where ClientID='56554a81-d98e-44ac-a5e1-611e564e55e8' 
  and cg.IsDeleted=0
```

As of now, if I apply `for json auto` to the query it returns json in following format:

```
       {
       "ClientContactGroupID": "97FD1910-E9B2-4185-AB20-C10F983C77D1",
       "ClientID": "56554A81-D98E-44AC-A5E1-611E564E55E8",
       "ContactGroupName": "country code",
       "IsDeleted": false,
       "gcon": [
        {
        "ClientContactID": "59ECC8D0-C2FA-4DEA-841C-00771CE445C4",
        "ClientContactGroupID": "97FD1910-E9B2-4185-AB20-C10F983C77D1",
        "FirstName": "aaa",
        "LastName": "bbb",
        "Email": "VgDIrd12tl3S1f21YzhE+CQZErF\/L0pIPkdz84ggTbjoxU969e797sD2V818OmZm",
        "MobilePhone": "\/deaMYIoAlgs4vfO8lQORQ=="
        }
   ]}
```

In this the `gcon` should list multiple records but is only returning one. I tried different approaches but none seem to give a proper result.

Table valued function used in first query:

```
ALTER FUNCTION Func_GroupContacts
(   
 -- Add the parameters for the function here
 @ClientContactGroupID varchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    select ClientContactID,ClientContactGroupID
         , FirstName, LastName, ProfileImage
         , Email, MobilePhone 
    from ClientContact 
    where ClientContactGroupID IN(@ClientContactGroupID) 
      and IsActive=1 
      and IsDeleted=0
)
```

[image]

Comment: What does this statement return without the `FOR JSON AUTO` clause?

Comment: @Zhorov i have added screen shot of the data.

Comment: The select statement you posted does not match the output for the JSON elements in the JSON output. Please post exactly what code you are running to get each result.